# Convert Excel Solver to Python Using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pulp

I've built out an example in Excel Solver just to demonstrate what I'm looking to start with in Python.  I tried with PuLP in Python but keep getting an error.  I'm trying to Minimize the Difference of df['AP'] and a input variable or simply just Maximize Profit.

[image: Excel Solver]

```
idx = df.index

#Define Inclusion Variable as Boolean
x1 = LpVariable.dicts("idx", idx, lowBound=-1, upBound = 1)

#Objective
prob += sum([x1[l] for l in idx]), 'Max of Profit'
#prob += lpSum([costs[i]*ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]), "Total Cost of Ingredients per can"

#Constraints
prob += lpSum([df['CalcVar'][l] for l in idx]) <= curDy + 0.01, "CalcVar"
prob += lpSum([df['CalcVar'][l] for l in idx]) >= curDy - 0.01, "CalcVar"

#Wrap up & Solve
LpSolverDefault.msg = 1
prob.writeLP('LaneOpt.lp')
prob.solve()
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solver.py", line 84, in <module>
    prob.solve()
  File "PATH", line 1671, in solve
    status = solver.actualSolve(self, **kwargs)
  File "PATH", line 1362, in actualSolve
    return self.solve_CBC(lp, **kwargs)
  File "PATH", line 1427, in solve_CBC
    raise PulpSolverError("Pulp: Error while executing "+self.path)
pulp.solvers.PulpSolverError: Pulp: Error while executing ...\cbc.exe
```

Comment: Hi, dear user. Consider add a clear question, share your log if you have any error or make your question more readable. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I added my code that is causing the error.

Comment: That's better. If your code raise an error, can you show it ? Cause we can't run your code. Be as precise as possible and give details.

Comment: Added.  Thanks again!

Comment: does `LaneOpt.lp` look ok, if so maybe something is wrong with your pulp install.

Comment: It looks like this ```\* Maximize Number *\
Maximize
Max_Profit: Include
Subject To
Lower_Bounds_Constraint: Include >= 0.054
Upper_Bounds_Constraint: Include <= 0.074
Binaries
Include
End```